# Asymptotic expansion of the gamma function with imaginary value

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, gamma-function

For fixed $h>0$, consider the function
$$F(x) = e^{-x\pi/2} \left| \Gamma\left(h-i\frac x2\right)\right|^2.$$
What is its asymptotic expansion as $x\to 0$ or $x\to \pm\infty$?

For $x\to \pm\infty$, I only need the leading behavior, while for $x\to 0$, I need the first subleading term that depends on $x$.

I tried Mathematica, but it does not provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E9) known result
$$
\mathrm{e}^{ - x\pi /2} \left| {\Gamma \!\left( {h \pm \mathrm{i}\frac{x}{2} } \right)} \right|^2  \sim 2\pi \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)^{2h - 1} \mathrm{e}^{ -  x\pi} 
$$
as $x\to +\infty$ with any fixed $h>0$. As $x\to 0$, we have
$$
\mathrm{e}^{ - x\pi /2} \left| {\Gamma \!\left( { h\pm \mathrm{i}\frac{x}{2} } \right)} \right|^2  = \Gamma ^2 (h) - \frac{\pi }{2}\Gamma ^2 (h)x + \mathcal{O}_h(x^2 ).
$$
The absolute value of the gamma function is an even function, thus the more complicated behaviour is hidden in the $\mathcal{O}$-term. Only the exponential function contributes to the linear term.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica provides a useful answer.

**Hint**

Consider
$$\Gamma(h-\epsilon)=\Gamma (h)\left(1-  \psi ^{(0)}(h)\,\epsilon+\frac{1}{2}  \left(\psi ^{(0)}(h)^2+\psi
   ^{(1)}(h)\right)\,\epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right) \right)$$ Square it
$$\Gamma (h-\epsilon )^2=\Gamma (h)^2\left( 1-2   \psi ^{(0)}(h)\,\epsilon+\left(2 \psi ^{(0)}(h)^2+\psi
   ^{(1)}(h)\right)\,\epsilon ^2 +O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)\right)$$